# Accessing database using FirebaseUI for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebaseui

I am using FirebaseUI to use Firebase as data source for my UITableView. In firebase, I have two databases - Users & Request Posts. 
I want to populate my UITableView cells with the information in the "Request Posts" database. I tried running the below code and requestPostDatabase always turns out to be nil. I have tried several other ways but I can't get hold of the children of "Request Post Database".

```
self.datasource = self.tableView.bind(to: self.ref) { tableView, indexPath, snapshot in

            if let snap = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                let requestPostDatabase = snap["Request Posts"]
                print(requestPostDatabase)
            }

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell
            return cell
        }
```

I also tried doing,

```
let snap = snapshot.child("Request Posts")
```

to get hold of the Request Posts database, but for some reason the child() function is not available.

Comment: can u add to your question function of getting snapshot?

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand your question.

Comment: i believe you are trying to take data wrong. I will post answer soon

Comment: And can you please show your database structure? like printscreen

Comment: Has it helped?:)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to use `@escaping` in function of getting data from Firebase.

Like you have your array of data for cells in controller:

```
var arrayOfData: [DataItem]()
```

Then function of getting data:

```
static func getData(completion: @escaping (_ data: [DataItem]) -> Void) {
  var data = [DataItem]()
  let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(...).child... // your ref
  ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
     // here you need to parse data and fill array from snapshot
     // and data.append(/*your parsed data*/)
     // then return data to completion handler
     completion(data)
  })
}
```

Like this. You should get the idea.

Then you can, for example, in viewDidLoad() use function:

```
getData(completion: { newData in 
    self.data = newData
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

And then you can use this array to fill your tableView

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Do you know how could I achieve this in FirebaseUI - https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/FirebaseDatabaseUI

Comment: If it helped - mark it pls. Btw - no, i haven't, because I'm not sure if it is a good for MVC. I have a model layer of communicating with Firebase database/storage. I haven't got any "import Firebase" in my view layer. But its your choice. Good luck:)

Comment: @pranavhgupta anyway. Can you show your self.ref binding? like let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(...)

Comment: I have defined a "var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!" in my ViewController and "ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()" in my viewDidLoad(). Haven't used ref anywhere else.

Comment: @pranavhgupta I think your reference is wrong. You should specify path to your data. Like .....reference().child("something").child("anotherSomething") or reference(withPath: "something/anotherSomething"). And then use it. Its my oppinion

Comment: @pranavhgupta just make a research of your snapshot content. Good luck. I hope, I have helped you with something